# SQL Server : query that determines binary state in new column, lists most recent row per group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looked all over for a similar situation, but couldn't find a solution. Perhaps it's too complicated without using a temporary table?

I want to be able to create a new column that shows whether a customer has ever used a coupon.  Along with that, want to extract the most recent purchase, and sort by last name.

I've been able to get the latest transaction by partitioning but can't find the logic to find the coupon users can this be efficiently done in one step, or does it have to be output to a temporary table?

Input data:

```
TransDateTime       TransID CustID  FirstName   LastName    NumItems    TotalAmt    CouponUsed
2018-01-09 11:57:24 39451634836 334096  Al  Einstein    5   $1,420.44   Coupon
2018-01-14 17:15:25 39451634837 299080  George  Clooney 1   $816.64 
2018-01-15 19:34:42 39451634838 212950  Stephanie   Germanauto  2   $2,583.64   
2018-01-15 22:32:06 39451634839 258006  Sandy   Bullock 2   $718.36 
2018-01-16 23:34:23 39451634840 212950  Stephanie   Germanauto  3   $1,432.63   
2018-01-18 09:38:39 39451634841 299080  George  Clooney 8   $1,073.50   
2018-01-18 19:36:42 39451634842 258006  Sandy   Bullock 4   $1,035.75   Coupon
2018-01-20 05:58:48 39451634843 334096  Al  Einstein    3   $1,145.06   
2018-01-25 12:16:11 39451634844 212950  Stephanie   Germanauto  7   $1,059.55   
2018-01-31 11:09:41 39451634845 258006  Sandy   Bullock 6   $633.98 Coupon
2018-02-02 14:17:44 39451634846 299080  George  Clooney 9   $925.55 
2018-02-03 19:57:32 39451634847 212950  Stephanie   Germanauto  6   $685.47 Coupon
```

Output data:

```
TransDateTime   TransID CustID  FirstName   LastName    NumItems    TotalAmt    CouponUsed  CouponCust
2018-01-31 11:09:41 39451634845 258006  Sandy   Bullock 6   $633.98     Coupon  Yes
2018-02-02 14:17:44 39451634846 299080  George  Clooney 9   $925.55         
2018-01-20 05:58:48 39451634848 334096  Al  Einstein    3   $1,145.06       Yes
2018-02-03 19:57:32 39451634847 212950  Stephanie   Germanauto  6   $685.47     Coupon  Yes
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Is that output what you're currently getting or what you want to get? And what is the query you have so far?

Comment: Thanks, @marc_s for cleaning up the data!  I used "code."  What did you use to tidy it up?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight them - or just insert the code or sample data by at least four spaces from the left

Comment: Yes @Xedni, that is the output I needed.  John Cappelletti showed me what works well.

Comment: Thanks, @marc_s!  I'lI try it your way next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use window function `Max() over ()`

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select *
      ,CouponCust = max(case when CouponUsed='Coupon' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) over (Partition By CustID)
      ,RN         = Row_Number() over (Partition By CustID order by TransDateTime Desc)
 From  YourTable
) 
Select *
 From  cte 
 Where RN=1
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: @SquareDonut Happy to help.

Comment: @SquareDonut If you like, please ACCEPT the answer

Comment: Thanks, John! This is exactly what I was trying to do. I looked at "max()", but I don't understand why it works. What is it taking the maximum of? It would seem that "case" by itself should work. Can you shed some light?

Comment: @SquareDonut This is the window function max() over ().   So if the customer EVER used a coupon, it would return Yes.  Yes is greater than No or blank.   Try the query without the WHERE RN=1.   You may get a bit more insight.

Comment: @SquareDonut BTW the window functions can be invaluable.  they are well worth your time getting comfortable with them

Comment: Thanks, John.  I'll play with this to understand it better.